# What is the difference between mysqli::real_connect and new mysqli object in connecting database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using this method to connect to `mysql` db :

```
$this->_Con = new mysqli($this->_DB['Server'],$this->_DB['User'],$this->_DB['Pass'],$this->_DB['DB']);
```

What is the difference when I connect using this method:

```
$this->_Con = mysqli_init();
$this->_Con->real_connect($this->_DB['Server'],$this->_DB['User'],$this->_DB['Pass'],$this->_DB['DB']);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its just another way of connecting to your database. If you use [`mysqli_init()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.init.php) it will initialize the `mysqli` object first. Then using the object you will call [`real_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) to connect to the database. But when you use [`new mysqli()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) you are initializing the `mysqli` object by passing in the connection values as parameters, So it does initialization and connection at the same time.

**Note: Calling the constructor with no parameters is the same as calling mysqli_init().**

In your first case you are getting the connection object as the return value because you are calling `mysqli()` constructor with parameters. So you can run queries on it. But in your second case you need to store the connection like this,

```
$con = $this->_Con->real_connect($this->_DB['Server'],$this->_DB['User'],$this->_DB['Pass'],$this->_DB['DB']);
```

Then run queries on `$con`

Comment: So you mean that my $this->_Con will be the same with these 2 method??
But when i try to use the second method, i guess my insert statement fails to insert new row. Do you have any idea why??

Comment: @user1650716 Generally you use *either* the object from `new mysqli()` *or* the structure from `mysql_init()`. Not both.

Comment: i cant run prepare query.. it says: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object.. can you please show me an example on how can i run insert query with prepared statements??

Comment: or my true goal is to set MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS from affected rows to matched rows when running update statements, is there a way to achieve this without using real_connect??

Comment: @user1650716 can you post how you are using ur prepared statements ? update your question!!