# What is the difference between mysqli::connect and new mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Mysqli library offers a number of alternative syntaxes for establishing connection to the MySQL server.

#### #1

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

#### # 2

```
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

I am not asking about [procedural vs OOP style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707696/new-mysqli-vs-mysqli-connect) nor am I asking about [`mysqli_connect()` vs `mysqli_real_connect()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719826/what-is-the-difference-between-mysqlireal-connect-and-new-mysqli-object-in-con).

What is the **purpose** of the `mysqli:connect()` method, and **is there any difference between connecting using the first option and the second option**?

Comment: `new mysqli` calls `__construct()` which calls `connect`, no difference.

Comment: Have a look at php.net/mysqli_connect - both are synonym

Comment: Why would you expect a difference? What kind of difference are you interested in? You'll find many things that can be accomplished in many different ways across the language (and many other languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference.

If you call `new mysqli` with arguments, it calls `$this->connect()` with those arguments automatically.

Otherwise it leaves the `mysqli` object unconnected, and you have to call the `connect()` method explicitly. That's what method 2 is doing.

Using separate calls can be useful if you need to call `mysqli::options()` before connecting. Some of the options affect connecting to the DB, e.g. `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`, so you need to set them before calling `mysqli::connect()`